# How can I add or subtract numbers to a counter with a button using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm new to javascript and code in general, and I'm stuck.
I would like that when I click on a button the counter increases by x numbers.
For example a button +100 or -100 and with each click it increments the counter.

I tried that but the button only works once.

```
            <script>
                price = 100
                money = document.getElementById('money').value
                function buyButtonClick(){
                    document.getElementById('money').value = money-price;
                }
            </script>
```

```
<input type="text" id="money" value="200"></input>
<button onclick ="buyButtonClick() id="buy-button">buy</button>
```

Comment: move `money = document.getElementById('money').value` inside the function. At the moment it only gets set once at page load and will never update.

Comment: Also break a bad habit right away of not properly declaring variables using `var, let or const` or you will soon run into hard to debug problems due to variable collisions

Comment: also make sure it's always a number by using the shorthand `+` :: `money = +document.getElementById('money').value`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to get a current value each time from `#money` so move that into your function. You also need to ensure it's a number (since all values taken from elements are strings), so add the + in front. Finally, you probably don't want it to go below zero, so you can use `Math.max()` to make sure it doesn't go into the red.

```js
let price = 100
function buyButtonClick() {
  money = +document.getElementById('money').value
  document.getElementById('money').value = Math.max(0, money - price);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="money" value="200"></input>
<button onclick="buyButtonClick()" id="buy-button">buy</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First querySelect the button, onclick of which you want to increment it to 100,
then change the value displayed by the `innerHTML` property of DOM.

```js
const price = 100;
buttonIncrement.addEventListener("click", () => {
  
counterDisplay.innerHTML = parseInt(counterDisplay.innerHTML,10) + price;
})
```

The complete solution is here ->
https://codepen.io/rashitamehta/pen/poPPGVP

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use let, const, or var while declaring variables like in your code "money"

Secondly, you can query or get the Elements at the beginning itself instead of doing it repeatedly inside the function, something like this:

```
let counterVal = document.getElementById("money");
```

Remember, the input field always receives values in string therefore when it's a number it needs to be parsed with `parseInt(<value>)` this will help avoid math functions or complications. Also you can self close the input tag, you don't need a separate closing tag like this

I built a sample for your understanding (added a bit of CSS in there):

**HTML**

```
<h1>Counter</h1>
<input class="result" type="text" id="money" value=500 />
<button onClick="valInc()">Increase</button>
<button onClick="valDec()">Decrease</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.result {
  width: 20em;
  height: 1.2em;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1em;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button {
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 6em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: hsl(249, 47%, 34%);
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
let counterVal = document.getElementById("money");

function valInc () {
  counterVal.value = parseInt(counterVal.value) + 100;
}

function valDec () {
  counterVal.value = parseInt(counterVal.value) - 100;
}
```

Hope this is helpful in some manner!!

Answer (score -1):

the code would be like this:

```
 <script>
    price = 100
    function buyButtonClick(){
    money = document.getElementById('money').value
    document.getElementById('money').value = money-price;
    }
</script>
```